# CSS to fill container div with child while preserving aspect ratio (as with background-size: contain)

Tags: html, css

I am designing an HTML5 card game that will run as a mobile app, and need the #table div to scale to fill but not overflow the offsetParent div while maintaining the table's correct aspect ratio of 68%. This means that it should adjust its size to fill but not overflow **either** parent width and parent height so that it works in both portrait and landscape.

An example is how *background-size: contain* works when setting the background image. Only I'm not trying to set the background image, I'm trying to set the size of a child div. This way I can use percentage values for all subsequent elements on the table and have the game look exactly the same with exactly the same aspect ratio at all sizes.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my code. See how the table is chopped off on the bottom for wide and short screen sizes:

http://vedanamedia.com/clients/intuitive-eye/speakeasy/

**UPDATE 2**

I am going for something just like this (jsfiddle.net/webtiki/dAebS) or this (dabblet.com/gist/2590942) except it also respects the shrinking height of the container.

Comment: just like this (http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/dAebS/) or this (http://dabblet.com/gist/2590942) except it also respects the shrinking height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the default height, and adding padding bottom to create the correct aspect ratio and ensure it remains the same when re-sized.

I'm not completely sure I understand what you mean by 68% as you don't have a code pen setup, but I've added below an example for something which is an aspect ratio of 2:1 to see if this might be a possible fix for you.

```
div {

    padding-bottom: 50%;
    height: 0;

}
```